# How to use an object constructor to initialize values on a PFObject subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, initialization

Question regarding Swift and PFSubclassing.  I have a class called WeatherNotification which is a subclass of PFObject.  My class contains an init method that lets me set values when creating the object.

```
init(temp: Int) {
    self.temp = temp
}
```

However the compiler complains that I don't have super.init in there before I try and initialize a variable.

When I put super.init() in there above the self.temp line then I get a complaint at runtime.

```
weatherNotification.swift: 39: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented 
initializer 'init()' for class 'perfectweather.WeatherNotification
```

Is there a different object initializer approach i need to use here?  Do I need to switch to initializing via the properties?

Xcode 6.3.2 is being used.  Parse API 1.7.5 is the parse api version

EDIT:  I ended up switching from an init method to a setValues method which would take in the values I wanted to set on the object.  That got me away from the init issues.  However, I would like to understand what happened better so I'm leaving the question open!

Comment: I have no experience with parse.com, but this looks closely related: [Subclassing PFObject in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581981/subclassing-pfobject-in-swift).

Comment: @martinR that references a slightly tangential bug in an earlier version of parse.

Comment: Just a note: Swift requires the super init to be called last. So `super.init()` should be called after the `self.temp = temp` line

Comment: @KRiz I think that is the answer!