# The class must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, key-value-observing, pfobject

I’m using KVO for a property in a subclassed `PFObject` which is already registered during initialize.

Everything is fine if I use 1 object. On the second object I get the error `The class KVO_vs_PFObject.MyModel must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse.` I need multiple objects to observe properties.

I tried to use property `observer(didSet)` as an alternative on swift but the compiler won't let me since I'm using a managed property.

Does anyone know what's going on with this code?

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MyModel : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "MyModel"
    }
    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
    @NSManaged var property1 : String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var myObject = MyModel()
        myObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "property1", options: .New, context: nil)
        myObject.property1 = "Hello"
        myObject.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "property1")

        // If I comment these 4 lines. myObject is happy observing the property.
        var anotherObject = MyModel()
        anotherObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "property1", options: .New, context: nil)
        anotherObject.property1 = "World"
        anotherObject.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "property1")
    }
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        var n : AnyObject? = change["new"]
        switch keyPath {
        case "property1" :
            println("observed MyModel.property1 with value \(n)")
        default :
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using computed property instead of stored property as per related post. [Subclassing PFObject in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581981/subclassing-pfobject-in-swift)

```html
//    @NSManaged var property1 : String?
    var property1: String? {
        get {
            return self["property1"] as? String
        }
        set {
            self["property1"] = newValue
            println("observed MyModel.property1 with value \(newValue)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my AppDelegate in addition to the initialize(). There were some posts here that say that initialize() needs some kick-starting before getting invoked. Worth trying the following...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        // Override point for customization after application launc

        //-----------------Parse customizations------------------------------


        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        // ****************************************************************************
        // Uncomment this line if you want to enable Crash Reporting
        // ParseCrashReporting.enable()
        //
        // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:

        //This one is for the MyAppName Parse App

        MyModel.registerSubclass()

        // Rest of the stuff...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Jitendra . I tried the appDelegate but didn't work. Still getting error if used with KVO on a second instance. The first instance is fine. It's just the second one bombs out.

Comment: Sorry Edgardo, in that case, I am not sure what is going on either. When I searched for initialize, I recall reading that the class must be referenced once before initialize is called. from your observation that it works first-time, maybe things go wrong after initialize().  my init code:                                                                           override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }