# Tip me about thread safety and UI

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am implementing a picture posting app by using parse.com. several days ago, I had an error on my app, which is

> 2015-10-22 14:36:52.501 bany[2595:874380] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array’

but my array was fine. then I posted stackOverFlow, someone told me this problem occurs that I did it wrong with thread safety and UI updating.

this is the post - index 0 beyond bounds for empty array, sometime works, sometime does not

I read about thread safety from apple reference, I figured out that using Mutable array is thread unsafe class type.

here is my code.

```
class MainTVC: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var categorySegment: UISegmentedControl!

var postsArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var filterdArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var objectTwo : PFObject!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    
    bringAllDatafromParse()
}

@IBAction func segmentTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Empty postArray
    postsArray = []
  
    // get post's data by categories
    switch categorySegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0 :
        bringAllDatafromParse()
    case 1 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(1)
        
    case 2 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(2)
        
    case 3 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(3)
        
    default :
        bringAllDatafromParse()
   }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return postsArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTVCE
    let postObjects = self.postsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    
    
    // IndexPath for comment button on tableView
    cell.didRequestToShowComment = { (cell) in
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let objectToSend = self.postsArray[indexPath!.row] as? PFObject
        // Show your Comment view controller here, and set object to send here
        self.objectTwo = objectToSend!
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToComment", sender: self)
    }
   
    
    // Show sold label or not
    cell.soldLabel.hidden = true
    
    if (postObjects.objectForKey("sold") as! Bool) == true {
        cell.soldLabel.hidden = false
    }
    
    
    // title Label of post
    cell.titleLabel.text = postObjects.objectForKey("titleText") as? String

    
    // nick name of user
    if let nickNameExists = postObjects.objectForKey("nickName") as? String {
       cell.nickNameLabel.text = nickNameExists
    }else {
        cell.nickNameLabel.text = postObjects.objectForKey("username") as? String
    }
    
    
    // time label for posts
    let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM /dd /yy"
    cell.timeLabel.text = (dateFormatter.stringFromDate(postObjects.createdAt!))
    
   
    // price label
    let price = (postObjects.objectForKey("priceText") as! String)
            cell.priceLable.text = "   $\(price)"
    
   
    // main Image for post
    let mainImages = postObjects.objectForKey("front_image") as! PFFile
    mainImages.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        cell.mainPhoto.image = image
    }
    
    
    //profile picture for user
    if let profileImages = (postObjects.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile){
                profileImages.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    cell.profilePhoto.image = image
        }
    }else{ cell.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "AvatarPlaceholder")
    }
    circularImage(cell.profilePhoto)
    
    
    
    return cell
}



func bringAllDatafromParse() {

    //empty postArray
    postsArray = []
    
    //bring data from parse
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil{
            for object : PFObject in objects! {

                self.postsArray.addObject(object)
            }
            let array : Array = self.postsArray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.postsArray = array as! NSMutableArray
        }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
   
    }

}


func bringCategoryDataFromParse(category : Int) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.whereKey("category", equalTo: category)
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil{
            for object : PFObject in objects! {
                self.postsArray.addObject(object)
            }
            let array : Array = self.postsArray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            
            self.postsArray = array as! NSMutableArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // send object to commentViewController
    if (segue.identifier == "mainToComment") {
        let destViewController : CommentVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentVC
        destViewController.object = objectTwo
    }
    
    // send object to DetailViewController
    if (segue.identifier == "mainToDetail") {
        let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let destViewController : DetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
            destViewController.object = (postsArray[(selectedRowIndex?.row)!] as? PFObject)

    }
}

func circularImage(image : UIImageView) {
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
    image.clipsToBounds  = true
    image.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

Here are thoughts about what I did wrong on my code during look into other's code.
So please comment these are right or not.

1. I should use NSArray instead of using NSMutableArray for thread safety.
   Will it be okay if  I use NSArray?
2. I will have separate data class for retrieving data includes checking nil or there is a value, instead of putting in the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" which would have 'only' define of cell for reuse.

If I do it this, should I retrieve data from array in most ViewControllers instead of using prepareSegue method to send specific(selected) object from mainViewcontroller which has function retrievingAllData?

3. should I use cache and dispatch_async in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"
   Is it mandatory?

4.UI part, I am really confused. Could anyone tip for this? For example, how does make UI showing progressing until data retrived done? You can tip just 'a' comment. It will be helpful a lot for me.   I really appreciate that.

please give me advise.

Comment: try commenting out this line: var objectTwo : PFObject!. you can't instantiate a PFObject at the top of the class unless it is a PFObject class (and your class is uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general tip, by using `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` (which can contain a collection of any type of object) you're loosing a lot of the benefit of using Swift's `Array` type (which can only contain one type of object).

The Parse `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method is already returning an Array of PFObjects so there isn't really any reason to switch to using an NSArray.

Like the name suggests `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is performing the block on a background thread (because it might take a while to complete and you don't want it to lock up your main thread where you UI updates are being performed).

Calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` starts of a chain of events that update your UI, so this should be called on the main thread. You can do this pretty easily with a GCD function `dispatch_async`. Here's an update of one of your methods to show both of these changes:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    // unwrap the optional array of PFObjects
    if let objects = objects {

        // reverse your objects
        self.postsArray = objects.reverse()

        // trigger update to table on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    // if objects is nil that means there was an some error
    else {
        // unwrap the optional error
        if let error = error {
            // do something about the error - present feedback etc
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, just directly using the objects array and using the `reverse` method makes the code a lot clearer.

You're also using `!` to force unwrap an optional, which isn't a good habit to get into. Optionals are a pretty core part of Swift and it would make sense to make sure you wrap your head around them and your code will be a lot safer and less likely to crash :)
http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/12/wrap-your-head-around-optionals-in-swift/

**Subclassing PFObject**

It's a completely optional step, but one of the most interesting things about using the parse API is the ability to subclass `PFObject`. So instead always having to access your object attributes like this:

```
postObjects.objectForKey("titleText") as? String
```

you can just do this:

```
postObjects.titleText
```

It takes a little setup which is described for swift in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581981/subclassing-pfobject-in-swift) and also in the [parse.com docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for detailed explains!